# Exception Handling ProxyError, OSError in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to exception handle these proxy errors, i am trying following with no success:

```
from requests.exceptions import ProxyError, SSLError, ConnectionError

def adding(self):

    headers={
      'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36'
    }

    url = 'url'

    r = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)

def run(self):
    while True:
          try:
              self.adding()
          except OSError as e:
          print 'OSError'

          except ProxyError as g:
          print 'ProxyError'
```

However when i run python script i still get errors in the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "xx.py", line 273, in run
    self.adding()
  File "xx.py", line 107, in adding
    r = self.session.get(url, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 502, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='url', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: url (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request',)))
```

Comment: where is `try` clause?

Comment: What you posted there isn't valid python code. Please post a [mcve] that shows how that exception is thrown and how you're catching it.

Comment: @IvanVinogradov sorry edited

Comment: @Aran-Fey edited

Comment: can you add a full error traceback?

Comment: @IvanVinogradov edited

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe it. The code still isn't runnable, and the indentation is still all over the place. I don't see how an exception could possibly escape a `try ... except` block, and code that doesn't even start doesn't do anything to help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` statements below your exceptions are not indented to be part of their respective `except` statements, and your `try` does not seem to be indented correctly.  I'm not sure if that solves your problem or not, but it does appear to be unintentional.